# Getting an unknown extension of a file

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a directory path for files that include the name of the file itself, but the extension of the files have been deleted. I have:

```
Path = "repository/something/306/072/437/985/825"
```

where `825` is the name of the file without an extension. This file can either be `.jpg` or `.txt` extension.

I cannot find any functions in ruby for detecting the extension of a file if I have not been given the extension. Anyways to do this?

Comment: Note that a file extension is just a convention, and os it is not one-to-one. Even if you were to find out what file format the file is written in, you cannot pick the extension automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to detect the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of a file.

In Linux, you could determine the MIME via  `file --mime-type`. So, one approach is to call the shell command:

`mime = %x[file --mime-type #{path} | cut -d' ' -f2]`

Or you can use [mimemagic](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic) gem to do it:

```
require 'mimemagic'

MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open('image.jpg')).type # => "image/jpeg"
```